# convert a number in a string to float in c: atof(), strtof() do not work

Tags: c

My C is rusty. I am trying to convert a string to float (or double). I have tried atof() and strtof(), and tried following instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951019/convert-string-to-float) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756939/gnu-c-atof-strtof-and-strtod-fail-debian-for-beagleboard). No luck.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  float x;
  char a[20];
  strcpy(a,argv[1]);
  x = strtof(a);
  printf("%s\n",a);
  printf("%f\n",x);
  return 0;
}
```

No luck. Here's output, on the command line:

```
prompt$ ./a.out 2.34
2.34
1426063.000000
prompt$
```

If I use atoi() instead, I get 0.0.

Clearly there is something simple I'm missing. This is with gcc 4.8.4 on ubuntu fwiw.

Makes no difference if I compile with -static flag, or use double instead of float (and %e instead of %f), or include math.h. The output changes in some of those cases, but it's still nonsense.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to float in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191034/convert-string-to-float-in-objective-c)

Comment: Did you disable warnings or what? The prototype for `strtof()` looks rather different than what you seem to think.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't included `<stdlib.h>` to get [`strtof()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtod.3.html)'s prototype. So the return type defaults to int. But implicit int rule has been removed from C since C99.

The usage is also wrong. It should be, at least:

```
char *eptr;

x = strtof(a, &eptr);
```

And inspect `eptr` for conversion failures.

Compile with warnings enabled. GCC warns with:

> warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strtof’
>   [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: OK thanks. I hadn't disabled warnings, and I didn't get one, but that was clearly the problem. Including stdlib.h, and adding a second argument "NULL" to strtof(), together fixed it. However, I think the usage  of strcpy() was actually correct; argv[1] is already a pointer.

Comment: Ooops, you meant the usage of strtof(), not strcpy(). Yes, you are right, my usage of strtof() was incorrect (sigh).